# How do you make a UIWebView content editable?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've been reading that you can edit the content of a UIWebView as of iOS 5, but has this feature since been removed?

I'm working off of iOS 7, and I don't see any such feature available. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the content, you need to mark it as `contentEditable=true` in the HTML. If not, you need to enable it using JavaScript once the web view finishes load:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.setAttribute('contentEditable','true')"];
```